# iOS: Linking a third party framework and crashing when deploying

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So, my problem is that I'm creating a framework to be used with iOS. It works great when in the simulator and when I'm debugging it on my iPad but as soon as I send it to anyone via Testflight (including my iPad) it crashes. The application will load the splash screen, then crash.

I tried symbolicating the report but I'm not getting anything out of it.

Answer (score 1):

One time happened to me... xcode compiles the app for debug on the simulator, but for release on the iOS device. Then, the debug version doesn't do many enhancements.

Go to "Product" -> "Manage Schemes". There, if I were you, I would set everything to "Build Configuration": Release.

This way, you may be able to have the simulator crash... and it may be easier for you to figure out what's going on.

In my case, I was using a block but not copying it... then, on the release version, the compiler cleared the memory while on the debug version it didn't.

Hope it helps

Comment: No dice, still crashing. See my answer for what I did.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution to my problem was that I was linking the framework but not copying it to the device, so when I debugged it with my iPad connected to it, it would find the references to the framework, but once it was deployed, the app crashed when it tried to find the framework.

The answer was:

1. Go to your project's build phases.
2. Add build phase > Add copy files.
3. Choose Frameworks in the Destination field.
4. Copy the framework.

Your app should now have the framework copied and installed wherever it needs.

Comment: Sounds like the framework is a dylib, yeah? Apple won't accept apps linked against third-party dylibs in the App Store, last I heard. Just fyi.

Comment: Agree to @davehayden. This will not work. You need to create a static library instead of a framework. There are ways to simulate frameworks which result in static frameworks in the end, see: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

Comment: It's not a dylib file. I created it by using this method: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

Comment: This solved my problem temporarily. No idea why it works only sometimes.